# 1.9 - Extending catalog/product controller breaks catalog/category

Tags: controllers, extend

I'm trying to add an action "sample" to the product controller which was going fine. I wanted the url `domain.com/catalog/product/sample/sku/{sku}/` so here's what I did:

1. Added file **Org_Catalog.xml** in **app/etc/modules/**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
     <modules>
       <Org_Catalog>
         <active>true</active>
         <codePool>local</codePool>
       </Org_Catalog>
     </modules>
   </config>
   ```
2. Added **config.xml** in **app/code/local/Org/Catalog/etc/**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <config>
   <modules>
       <Org_Catalog>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Org_Catalog>
   </modules>   

   <frontend>
       <routers>
           <Catalog>
               <use>standard</use>
               <args>
                   <module before="Mage_Catalog">Org_Catalog</module>
                   <frontName>catalog</frontName>
               </args>
           </Catalog>
       </routers>
   </frontend>    
   </config>
   ```
3. Added **ProductController.php** in **app/code/local/Org/Catalog/controllers/**

   ```
   <?php
   require_once 'Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php';

    class Org_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Catalog_ProductController{

       public function sampleAction(){
           Mage::Log("reached sample action");
       }
   }
   ```

Everything here was working fine but then I noticed the category page has stopped working. All category pages now go to 404 pages. The url translates to `domain.com/catalog/category/view/id/4` for one of the category. I didn't touch any of the `CategoryController.php` files or anything else. I can't tell why it's not working.

**Edit:** Just for a try, I added **CategoryController.php** in **app/code/local/Org/Catalog/controllers** and filled it with

```
<?php

require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Catalog').DS.'CategoryController.php');

class Org_Catalog_CategoryController extends Mage_Catalog_CategoryController{

}
```

This made the category page load. It seems that what I did has completely disabled the original catalog module, not extended it. Magento is not looking for the files in the core even though it didn't find it in the local folder. I just wanted to add an action so is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that anything with a catalog controller would be dying based on your code is the incorrect path being used for require_once. You need to use a path relative to the Magento install root. Try this:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Catalog').DS.'ProductController.php
```

---

I have just created a working example. It works for me at `http://local.datafeed.com/catalog/product/sample/`

**app/code/local/Org/Catalog/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Org_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Org_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <catalog>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Org_Catalog before="Mage_Catalog">Org_Catalog</Org_Catalog>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </catalog>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Org/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php**

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Catalog').DS.'ProductController.php';
class Org_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Catalog_ProductController {

    public function sampleAction()
    {
        echo "reached sample action!";
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: It's likely to be one of your problems so I would keep it. Have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: Yes, I'm keeping the version you suggested. Also take a look at the updated question

Comment: Try `<module before="Mage_Catalog_Product">Org_Catalog_Product</module>`

Comment: Also if you have not yet uncommented the ini_set display errors line inside index.php you should go ahead and do that bc it may very well reveal the error.

Comment: Error reporting is on. I didn't get any errors. Anyway, I ended up making it a seperate module instead of an extension of core. The only difference is of the url. I can live with that. If anyone else encounters a similar problem and the above comment helps out, let us know.

Comment: I've been writing these possible solutions blind, meaning on my phone without a computer. If you want to send me what you have I can prob make it work the way you want. It's probably one small issue bc I have added pages within the scope of core controllers many times before.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, but I've already added all the codes related to this in the question. I didn't do anything else. I'm surprised as well why it isn't working.

Comment: Ive updated the answer with a working example. The problem is the way you had your controller configured in config.xml.

Comment: Have you had a chance to verify my solution? It's exactly what you were looking for

Comment: Hey thanks Shawn, it's working. I see now I'm only overriding the product class not the whole catalog front name